# Controlling transparency for basemap layer in ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: arcgis-android

The options seem sparse, but maybe I'm missing something (I'm new to both ArcGIS for Android and Android Honeycomb). Is there a way to make the basemap transparent?

Update: this question is on the Esri application available in the [android market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.android.client&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd).

[image: Screenshot from ArcGIS Android 1.0.1, build87]

Comment: If this is an ongoing issue with the latest release can this question perhaps be edited with your latest findings.  Hopefully that may stimulate an Accept-able Answer like someone submitting an ArcGIS Idea to have an apparent software limitation lifted.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a way to change the transparency of a basemap loaded in the ArcGIS app available in the Play Store.  The only way to control the transparency of the basemap is to use ArcGIS Online and set the transparency of the webmap there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just set the base layer opacity before adding it to the MapView.

So something like

```
    MapView map;
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer backgroundMap = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("your map");
    backgroundMap.setOpacity("float");
    map.addLAyer(backgroundMap);
```

Comment: In the client? Wouldn't this code be on the server side?

Comment: all a base map is a layer so I don't see why not.

Comment: Even if the API supports it, the question is on Esri's ArcGIS for Android application.  I'll add the link to the market for clarification.  Which I re-installed a few minutes ago and still don't see a way to control transparency for a base map layer.

Comment: oh sorry thought you were building your own.

Comment: no worries. you might want to edit/remove the answer.  I'm not the downvoter (it's poor form to downvote w/o a reason why).